# Angular Router Weird Behavour - Double Html and Cannot match any routes: ''

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Simple App, made with Angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.18, AngularFire2

With the below code, the router is throwing this error:
`XCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''`

It works, but its giving an error. So, to remove the erroe i added another route to the `RouterModule.forRoot()`

`{path: '', component: AppComponent}`

And then changes the index.html file to remove `<app-root>` and removed the selector in the AppComponent, and out the `router-outlet` in the index.html.

With the changes, the error goes away, but i'm left with double instances of AppComponent, which looks like this:

[image]

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <span>
            <md-icon class="icon-20">work</md-icon>
            MyPA
        </span>
        <button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
            <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
        </button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-menu x-position="before" #menu="mdMenu">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/accounts" md-menu-item>Accounts</a>
    </md-menu>
    <pre>{{accounts | async | json}}</pre>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

accounts: FirebaseListObservable<Account[]>;

constructor(
    private Accounts: Accounts
){
  this.accounts = Accounts.getAll();
}

ngOnInit(){}
```

}

app.module.html

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'accounts', component: AccountsComponent}
    ]),
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(myFirebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig)
  ],
  providers: [
      Accounts
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you please add your routing.ts file, as you have problem in that?

Comment: @ParthChokshi I don't have a separate file. App is too small yet. So, all routing is in AppModule itself.

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't see ur app.module properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line in your routings

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent }
```

you tell the router that he should navigate at the `''`-path to the `AppComponent`. But you have your root-`router-outlet` inside your `AppComponent` so the router loads the AppComponent into the root-`router-outlet` which is itself inside this `AppComponent`.

You see the problem? You should not use the AppComponent anywhere in your router settings because the router loads initially the `AppComponent` with its root-`router-outlet`. And then the router loads all of the other routes with its components into this root-`router-outlet`.

So try to create another component for the empty `''`-route and you will be fine.

Comment: Why can't i just ignore that route? Shouldn't it just default to the bootstrap component?

Comment: The router is initialized inside the bootstrap component which is our `AppComponent`. After the router has been initialized it searches for the first `router-outlet` that is available - this is the outlet of our `AppComponent`. And now the router wants to know which component he should load inside the `router-outlet` of our `AppComponent`. So this must be another component than the `AppComponent`. The `AppComponent` cannot load itself into its own `router-outlet`.